# MOSS Anti-Virus

Tags: security, sharepoint, moss, antivirus

Our server already has symantic anti-virus with autoprotect enabled w/ regular scans and updates. I tested it and it does automatically scan uploaded files to document libraries.

My question is, what additional benefit is there to using a specific anti-virus plugin instead of this current setup? There are at least 3 different plugins I can find including one from symantic, avg and microsoft. None of the product descriptions really say what it does although I'm guessing it might add a "scan this file" link inside MOSS.

Comment: StackOverflow is for answering programming questions. You may be able to get help with this at one of the sites listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Comment: Why does the tag called "not-programming-related" exist?

Comment: Because people do still ask questions that are not programming related and because it is community moderated, there isn't always agreement over whether a question should be closed or not. The tag allows people that don't want to see these questions to add it to their ignore list.

Comment: AFAIK any documents uploaded to a doc library only exist as BLOB's in the database, never as physical files in the file system - therefore I am not sure how you normal Symantic AV can check these - how have you determined that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you might want a specific SharePoint anti-virus solution is for scanning inside SharePoint lists. For example, traditional virus scanners cannot scan inside document libraries and attachments to list items.

This *might* be overkill if every user of your MOSS solution has anti-virus on their desktops as these will scan a Word document when it is opened from SharePoint. Even though, there is an argument for having a different vendor's anti-virus product installed on your servers from what is installed on your desktops as extra protection (e.g. one product's scanning heuristics might be a little different or its virus signatures might be older).

You need to weigh up the cost/benefit ratio and ask what importance your company gives to security.

Answer (score 0):

With MOSS you mean Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server?

Anyhow: the Anti-Virus in your case is signature dependent; what simply means that it recognizes files as infected if they match a signature. I guess the plugins have different feature sets for Macros in documents, or different GUIs... Shouldn't be that big difference.